# highlight preprocessor DEBUG blocks

Tags: vim

I want to highlight everything between `#ifdef DEBUG` and `#endif`

I tried this:

```
syntax match DEBUG /#ifdef DEBUG.*?#endif/
hi DEBUG ctermfg=green ctermbg=white
```

But it doesn't highlight the DEBUG blocks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `region` instead of `match` like this:

```
syntax region DEBUG start=/#ifdef DEBUG/ end=/#endif/
```

<sup>The relevant help files are `syn-match` and `syn-region`.</sup>